# Python library for reading data from fingerprint devices

Tags: python, fingerprint

I have heard of pygame (for games and reading from webcam) in python. And also gstreamer for media in python. Is there any python library that one can use for fingerprint reading and recognition.

Comment: What kind of fingerprint reading device?

Comment: any usb fingerprint device connected to the computer or even the ones that come with the computer itself

Comment: Any of those devices will have different drivers and require different libraries to work with- saying "the computer" doesn't specify anything. If you have an Ethentica scanner, for example, you can use [pyfinger](http://www.isp.drik.net/pyfinger/index.html), which is a wrapper around it. Similar wrappers probably exist for other devices, but there is no such thing as a single library that will read from all fingerprint scanners.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Most built-in fingerprint readers use WBF drivers these days for compatibility with Windows Hello...

Comment: Can you get the data from the device? If so I can write you a library to check for a match.